# How to clearly differentiate sort by creation vs sort by comments

Tags: controls, labels, sorting

### Scenario

I have a page that shows a list of items to which users can post comments. The user can choose to sort by the item's creation date the last time a comment was posted.

### Problem

I'm currently labeling the sort options as follows

- **`Sort by date added`**
- **`Sort by latest`**

This doesn't seem right to me. Is there a way to differentiate this type of sorting that will make the difference clear for users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Just say what you mean

Sometimes you just have to say it out loud. What is the most succinct way to clearly describe it in plain language? It also helps to ask others in a sort of guerrilla testing format.

As I see it:

> One is sorted by **date posted**.
>   The other by **latest comment**.

Answer (score 1):

"Sort by recent **activity**"

A quick google search shows that it seems to be used. For example [here](https://support.honey.is/hc/en-us/articles/206381378-Can-I-sort-my-feeds-by-recent-activity-).

Comment: Would this be for the "Sort by date" or "Sort by latest" option?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is

- **Date created** (the date file was actually created)
  and
- **Date modified** (the date the file was modified for the last time)

Also note there's a 3rd common option (usually when dealing with files) should you need it:

- **Date accessed** (the date the file was accessed/viewed without any modification)

These labels comes from the [UNIX timestamps](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/04/atime-ctime-mtime-in-unix-filesystems/) and are widely used nowadays, but it was also adopted by Windows for its File Explorer (see first example below) and Mac OS (see second example below)

## Examples:

Windows File Explorer
[image: date created vs date modified Windows]

Mac Finder
[image: date created vs date modified Mac]

**Other software:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]